# Javascript array of objects retaining the last value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to make a deck out of card objects in Javascript (which I'm new to). I made a card class and a deck function which populates a deck array with card objects using a for loop. In this for loop I made it set the rank and suite (value field in Card class will be for comparing between cards). So at the end of each loop it shows all the cards which is awesome but when I attempt to print the entire deck it prints the array length worth of the last element. This is bologna because this is easy I just haven't gotten accustomed to j.s. Please lend me a hand in explaining why the array does this.

Here are the outputs:

```
1 of Spades
2 of Aces
3 of Clubs
4 of Diamonds
5 of Spades
6 of Aces
7 of Clubs
8 of Diamonds
9 of Spades
10 of Aces
Jack of Clubs
Queen of Diamonds
King of Spades
1 of Aces
2 of Clubs
3 of Diamonds
4 of Spades
5 of Aces
6 of Clubs
7 of Diamonds
8 of Spades
9 of Aces
10 of Clubs
Jack of Diamonds
Queen of Spades
King of Aces
1 of Clubs
2 of Diamonds
3 of Spades
4 of Aces
5 of Clubs
6 of Diamonds
7 of Spades
8 of Aces
9 of Clubs
10 of Diamonds
Jack of Spades
Queen of Aces
King of Clubs
1 of Diamonds
2 of Spades
3 of Aces
4 of Clubs
5 of Diamonds
6 of Spades
7 of Aces
8 of Clubs
9 of Diamonds
10 of Spades
Jack of Aces
Queen of Clubs
King of Diamonds
then this 52 times  
[ { rank: 'King', value: 12, suite: '', suit: 'Diamonds' },
```

---

```
//card object
var Card = {
    rank: 0,
    value: '',
    suite: ""
};
//deck object returns array of non shuffled deck

function Deck() {
    var deck = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        var card = Card;
        if (i % 4 == 0)
            card.suit = "Spades";
        if (i % 4 == 1)
            card.suit = "Aces";
        if (i % 4 == 2)
            card.suit = "Clubs";
        if (i % 4 == 3)
            card.suit = "Diamonds";

        card.value = i % 13;
        card.rank = card.value + 1;
        if (card.rank == 11)
            card.rank = 'Jack';
        if (card.rank == 12)
            card.rank = 'Queen';
        if (card.rank == 13)
            card.rank = 'King';
        console.log(card.rank + " of " + card.suit);
        deck.push(card);
    }


    console.log(deck);

    return deck;
};
```

Comment: You are missing an `e` in assignments `card.suit=`. It should be `card.suite=`

Comment: Also while doing `var card = Card`, you are just updating reference and that is and at the end you are updating same variable, so at last it will have value of last card all the time. You should have `Card` as function and do a `var card = new Card()` in loops. Also to avoid hoisting try to use `let`,

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The added `suit` is because you have a typo and are setting the `suit` property instead of `suite`. (`card.suit="Aces"; ....` )

The strange behavior you're facing is because you are not creating a new object from your card, You're just changing the previous object and adding it to the array, and since it's passed with reference, you're basically changing all cards in the array (Updating all of them on each loop). You need to new the Card object on each iteration, to create a new reference.

```
var card = new Card();
// Update card.
deck.push(card);
```